# divs em diagonal como fazer usando after e skew?

Tags: css, div

Gente eu estou precisando fazer um site em que as divisões fiquem em diagonais.

Me falaram para colocar uma borda no `after` da `div`, e usar a propriedade `skew`.

Mas a borda no `after` não esta aparecendo.

Abaixo coloco um exemplo do que quero.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: POSTA O CÓDIGO.

Comment: O que esteve tentando?

Comment: estava so testando.slide:after{
 border:2px solid red;
}

.slide {
 transform: skew(20deg);
 width: 100%;
 height: 700px;
 background: blue;
}

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Criação de div diagonal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238393/cria%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-div-diagonal)

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue atingir esse objetivo utilizando sim a propriedade css `transform`.

```css
div.skew {
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transform: rotate(358deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(358deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(358deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
  -o-transform: rotate(358deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(358deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate(0px);
}
.container {
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="skew">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="skew">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Tudo é uma jogada de design, você pode adicionar uma div com `skew` a um container com `overflow: hidden;`.
Dai basta você trabalhar com CSS pra conseguir o que deseja.

Comment: É, mas dessa forma vai transformar o conteúdo do div também.

Comment: Eu aconselharia a deixar o `transform` depois do `-ms-transform`. O último válido para o browser é o que será utilizado.
Nenhum efeito prático que eu saiba, mas é uma prática bem comum.

Comment: Obg gnt conseguir aqui ! mt obg