# Criação de div diagonal

Tags: html, css

Bom, estou com dúvidas sobre a criação de uma div, com dois elementos, separados por uma linha em diagonal, conforme a imagem abaixo, como posso realizar a criação ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- O texto deve manter-se reto
- A propriedade Skew, conforme orientada por alguns usuários, não funciona, pois distorce a imagem

Comment: Acho que isso pode resolver seu problema. [Solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48152/css-div-diagonal?rq=1)

Comment: skew não resolve, tanto que no próprio fiddle realizado, a imagem fica distorcida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como respondi em [**Como fazer botão Inclinado?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56827/3635) e [**Botão na diagonal só o lado esquerdo**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126094/3635), você pode usar pseudo elementos:

```css
.main-banner {
   width: 600px;
   height: 200px;
   background: #ccc;
   position: relative;
}

.main-banner > .banner-img {
   background: #fc0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 50%; /* pode ajustar a largura do Element 2 (foto)*/
   height: 100%;
}

.main-banner > .banner-l {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;/*faz os elementos pseudos acompanharem o elemento com a classe*/
  width: 50%; /* pode ajustar a largura do Element 1 (verde)*/
  height: 100%; /*Acompanha a altura do elemento*/

  /* altera a cor, deve ser a mesma corda do border no :before*/
  background-color: #01b215;
}

.banner-l:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  
  /*ajuste aqui*/
  
  border-top: 200px solid transparent;
  border-left: 100px solid #01b215; /*altere a cor aqui, deve ser a mesma cor do background-color no banner-l*/
  right: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-banner">
    <div class="banner-img">Banner</div>
    <div class="banner-l">Left</div>
</div>
```

Explicações:

- `border-top: 200px solid transparent;` o 200px deve ter a mesma altura do `main-banner`, ajustando a altura deve ajustar aqui.
- `border-left: 100px solid #CC0000;` este deve ter a mesma medida que o `right`, no entanto com o valor positivo, a deve ser a mesma do background-color no seletor `.banner-l`
- `right: -100px;` este deve ter o mesmo valor que o `border-left`, no entanto deve ser o valor negativo.

Comment: o `border-top` aceita valores em porcentagem ?

Comment: tudo bem, muito obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: remontei o código, porém, a borda não pega inclinação em todo o seu comprimento, ela fica reta de cima para baixo depois de um tempo

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65805/problemas-da-div

Comment: ta em localhost

Comment: @MuriloGambôa to lá no chat, vamos continuar lá

Answer (score 0):

Fiz algumas alterações na resposta do Guilherme Nascimento para que o "pseudo-elemento" seja responsivo caso, o banner venha a mudar de tamanho em todas as resoluções possíveis.

```js
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
 var pxH = 5.166666666666667;
 var pxW = 1;
 function adaptativeMainBanner(){
  var newWindowHeight = $(window).height();
  var newValueW = newWindowHeight / pxH;

  $(".pseudo-before").css({"border-top":newWindowHeight + "px solid transparent","right":"-" + (newValueW - 0.5) + "px","border-left":newValueW + "px solid #fff"});
  return windowHeight = newWindowHeight; 
 }
 $(window).resize(function(){
  adaptativeMainBanner();
 });
 $(document).ready(function(){
  adaptativeMainBanner();
 });
```

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,body{
 height:100%;
}
#main-banner-holder{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 display:flex;
}
#main-banner{
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 flex-grow:1;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
#main-banner > img{
 min-width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
#main-text-banner{
 position:relative;
 background-color:#fff;
 width:46.588541666666664%;
 height:100%;
 padding:12px;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 align-items:center;
}
#main-text-banner .pseudo-before{
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 width:0;
 height:0;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 z-index:5;
 border-top:620px solid transparent;
 border-left:120px solid #fff;
 right:-120px;
 /* 620pxH - 150pxW */
 /* 4,133333333333333 */
}
#main-text-banner > div{
 flex-grow:1;
 margin-top:16px;
}
#main-text-banner > div *{
 text-align:justify;
}
@media(max-height:300px){
 #main-banner > img{
  height:auto;
  max-height:200%;
 }
}
@media(max-height:500px){
 #main-banner > img{
  height:auto;
  max-height:140%;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="main-banner-holder">
  <div id="main-text-banner">
   <span class="pseudo-before"></span>
   <h2>Memento Mori</h2>
   <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</p>
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main-banner">
   <!-- Caso queira uma imagem de fundo: <img src="img/company/banners/main-banner.jpg"> -->
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Algumas considerações:

- Por que "pseudo-elemento"?

Bom, não é verdadeiramente um pseudo-elemento, mas um elemento qualquer, que segue o mesmo comportamento que o pseudo-elemento receberia.;

- Dependendo do grau de inclinação da linha separatória, ela gera um pequeno bug de 0.5px de separação da div pai, para isso, foi colocado um `"right":"-" + (newValueW - 0.5)` no `.css()`;
- O valor pxH é equivalente ao pxW, pois ajuda a definir altura do "pseudo-elemento" de acordo com a largura/altura da tela/main-banner;
- Algumas declarações CSS no banner, e nas divs que possuem conteúdo, como a declaração de `width:46...%` ou o `flex-grow;1` foram colocados para que a linha divida o conteúdo no centro da tela, sem essas declarações, a linha começaria de 50% na ponta superior, e acabaria em algo como 53~54% na linha inferior
- Para outros detalhes, deixe seu comentário, assim que eu ver, estarei respondendo